# I'm getting array dimension missing error

Tags: java

```
DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

for(int i = 0 ; i<date.size();i++){
   dt.addRow(new Object[](firstname(i),secondname(i),gender(i)));
}
```

I'm getting array dimension missing error. Why?

Comment: `new Type[]()` is not a valid statement. Use `{}` for an initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `{ }` because a row is composed of an array of objects.

```
dt.addRow(new Object[]{g(i),ti(i),to(i)});
```